# Adding relay to turn off laser printer from lpt port

Tags: power, esp8266

I intend to deploy an ancient, but perfectly fine HP Laserjet 2300L via parallel port to a jet direct (yes, ancient technology too)
As the printer is in the basement, and we only print rarely, I want to turn off the printer, when not in use.

Would it be possible to use the STROBE signal to trigger a (solid state) relay to turn on the printer for some minutes? Or would the SELECT IN pin from the jetdirect signal if the printer was needed for the forseable future, and turn off, when the queue is empty?

Or should I for a microcontroller to keep the STROBE from the printer until it's turned on, and to prevent power-on noise on BUSY to fool the jetdirect to think the signal is received?

I guess SEL, PE and BUSY should be simulated to allow the Jetdirect to send something in the first place.

[image: Parallel port]

Comment: Perhaps it's easier just to add a sonoff, and say "OK Google, turn on/off printer, then perhaps a schedule to turn it off at 1AM, in case somebody forgot to,

Comment: Sonoffs are not UL listed and should not touch mains power with a 10 foot pole.  Yes, I know they’re sold for that purpose, but they're sold by direct mail or on "platforms" like Amazon Marketplace, so they can smuggle them past the FTC and CPSC.  No reputable shop would ever sell them.  If you want a proper, safe mains appliance switcher that talks to Alexa and friends, there are loads of competent ones on the market.

Comment: "selin" (17) seems like a candidate, have you measured it in action?